# One to many relationship in a somehow big table - slow performance

Tags: mysql, laravel, eager-loading

I have this table source_data with source_data_details as its child with one to many relationship

```
source:
=======
id
name
create_by
create_datetime
status

source_field:
=============
id
source_id (FK from source.id)
name
data_type
max_length
default_value
special_field
status

source_data:
============
id
source_id (FK from source.id)
create_datetime
generated_code

source_data_details:
====================
id
source_data_id (FK from source_data.id)
source_field_id (FK from source_field.id)
sourve_data_value

allocation:
===========
id
source_data_id (FK from source_data_id)
create_by
create_datetime
researcher_id
status
```

basically what is happening is that, I can create a source, and specified the field for each source. I have the data inserted into the source_data and then allocate the data to people for them to research.

And now I have one source with 12 fields with 330673 records in source_data and 3961051 records in source_data details.

I am retrieving them using Laravel Eager Loading and it is really such a pain because it is very slow (8s-10s) in Test environment and 5s in Production. And yes I am using pagination to limit the data I am retrieving and retrieving 5 records at a time.

Additional information is that I also have added index to source_data_details.source_data_id and it did not really much, it just made the average retrieving time better (nearly 8seconds constant)

In my source_data model:

```
public function details()
{
    return $this->hasMany('SourceDataDetailsModel', 'source_data_id', 'id');
}

public function allocation()
{
    return $this->hasOne('AllocationsModel', 'source_data_id', 'id');
}
```

This is my eager loading:

```
$query = \SourceDataModel::with(
                                   array
                                   (
                                       'details',
                                       'allocation'
                                   )
                               );

 $query->where('source_id', '=', 1);
 Paginator::setCurrentPage($request['current_page']);
 $source_data = $query->paginate($request['record_count']);
```

Some of the things I am considering now:

- Remove source_data_details and put it into source_data (this will remove the dynamic feature) which will affect quite alot in other modules

Before I do this, I wanted to know if there is any other way. Any suggestion is very much appreciated.

Comment: It could be the connection between you and the server is slow and the test enviorments one. have you tested your connecton with the server. becouse there doesnt seem much wrong with your code

Comment: I am in the same LAN connection, connection is not the issue really. it is more on the code itself.

Comment: What when you die and dump the query like: `dd(SourceDataModel::where('source_id',1)->with(['details','allocation'])->get())` is it still slow?

Comment: it continues loading loading for 49s then gives out 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? If it does not show you check your `laravel.log` in `storage\logs`.

Comment: The problem was memory was exhausted, I have increased the memory limit. And it takes 36s - 42s for the query to be completed. yes it is slow.

Comment: You are loading/ retreving all the "details" related to the data wich would probably be alot making the query slow. Could you try to simply load the `SourceDataDetailsModel` and paginate or it.

Comment: Yes I am, because I am required to. But any ways to optimize this so that it will be faster? Do I need to change from eloquent to fluent? or any suggestion?

Comment: Fluent would be faster. example [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/laravel/comments/33qodf/raw_fluent_query_more_than_5x_faster_than_exact/)